# Create branch every time make new feature

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, branch

I'm new to versioning software and I use Gitlab for that purpose.

I'm working with a team so my question is: it is mandatory to create a new branch and push it every time I make a new feature, or it is just enough to create one branch and push it and every time I make change in code I just push it to the same remote branch that I have created?

```
git checkout -b feature_x

git push origin feature_x
```

Comment: That's up to you and your team to decide, there are many different models for working with version control and they may already have established a different one than you're recommended here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary.

Usually new branch is created for major set of changes but everything is up to you and how you would like to manage your repo.